# Fire event before closing p:dialog

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a requirement where there is a `h:form` with some input components in a `p:dialog`.
I want to show another confirmation dialog before user closes the `p:dialog`.

How can I achieve that?

Primefaces offers me only `onHide` and `onShow` events on `p:dialog`.
is there any event called `onBeforeHide`?

*Using: Primeface 3.5 JSF 2.1*

Comment: What about showing other dialog when the first one is hidden or just update the first dialog to show the content you want in the second? From the end user's point of view I wouldn't find very friendly to have another dialog displayed without the first one hiding. But that's my point of view...

Comment: @XtremeBiker : I know its a non user friendly approach, but that's the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

May be little late to answer this. This is an another approach to show an another dialog or prompt on close.

- Make the dialog property `closable=false` and `closeOnEscape=false` and handle the escape key event and introduce the custom close icon in the header. On click of image, you can cal the js method or remote command to show another popup.

  `<p:dialog widgetVar="dialogWidget" id="DlgWidgetId"
  resizable="false" closable="false" modal="true" closeOnEscape="false">
      <f:facet name="header">
          <h:outputText value=" Header Text"></h:outputText>
          <img id="closeIconId" src="../../images/close_icon.png" 
              height="16px" width="16px" onclick="openAnotherPopup()" />
      </f:facet>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).keyup(function(e) {
              if (e.which == 27)
                  $("#closeIconId").click();
          });
      </script>
      // Other contents in popup
  </p:dialog>`

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own:

This example works on PrimeFaces 5 (using PF shortcut, in your case call the widgetVar directly):

***javascript***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //first unbind the original click event
 PF('dialogWV').closeIcon.unbind('click');// in PrimeFaces 3.5 replace PF('dialogWV') with dialogWV (window scope)

 //register your own
 PF('dialogWV').closeIcon.click(function(e) {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure!");
    if(r) {
       PF('dialogWV').hide();
     }
    //should be always called
    e.preventDefault();
   });
 })
```

Keep in mind that you have to recall that if you update the dialog...

Comment: I had tried this approach. But there are many other scenarios in closing the dialog. How about `closeOnEscape`? (This also I can handle by binding key event) but how about calling `hide()` on widgetwar from any button or any method from managed bean. So Instead of handling all this scenarios I'm looking a generalized solution.

Comment: you can always override the prototype of [onHide](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/dialog/dialog.js#L389)

Comment: Also you can call `PF('dialogWV').closeIcon.click()` instead of `PF('dialogWV').hide()` from the button...